# Perfect fluid and Cauchy momentum equation

Tags: special-relativity, fluid-dynamics, relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

The [stress-energy tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) of a [perfect fluid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_fluid) is given by

$$T^{\mu\nu}=\left(\rho+pc^{-2}\right)u^\mu u^\nu+pg^{\mu\nu}$$

The [divergence of the stress-energy tensor is zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Conservation_law): $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$. Hence

$$\nabla_\mu\left(\rho+pc^{-2}\right)u^\mu u^\nu+\nabla_\mu pg^{\mu\nu}=0$$

Expanding the first term, and using the [product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) on the second term, yields

$$\nabla_\mu\rho u^\mu u^\nu+\nabla_\mu pc^{-2}u^\mu u^\nu+\left(\nabla_\mu p\right)g^{\mu\nu}+p\nabla_\mu g^{\mu\nu}=0$$

Using the product rule once again on the first term yields

$$\left(\nabla_\mu\rho u^\mu\right) u^\nu+\rho u^\mu\nabla_\mu u^\nu+\nabla_\mu pc^{-2}u^\mu u^\nu+\left(\nabla_\mu p\right)g^{\mu\nu}+p\nabla_\mu g^{\mu\nu}=0$$

By the [continuity equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation), $\nabla_\mu\rho u^\mu=0$. Hence

$$\rho u^\mu\nabla_\mu u^\nu+\nabla_\mu pc^{-2}u^\mu u^\nu+\left(\nabla_\mu p\right)g^{\mu\nu}+p\nabla_\mu g^{\mu\nu}=0$$

The [divergence of the metric tensor is zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry): $\nabla_\mu g^{\mu\nu}=0$. Hence

$$\rho u^\mu\nabla_\mu u^\nu+\nabla_\mu pc^{-2}u^\mu u^\nu+\left(\nabla_\mu p\right)g^{\mu\nu}=0$$

Finally, using [tensor contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction) on the last term yields

$$\rho u^\mu\nabla_\mu u^\nu+\nabla_\mu pc^{-2}u^\mu u^\nu+\nabla^{\nu}p=0$$

We now turn to the [Cauchy momentum equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_momentum_equation) in the [Euler equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_%28fluid_dynamics%29#Euler_equations):

$$0=\rho\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\vec{u}\cdot\vec{\nabla}\right)\vec{u}+\vec{\nabla}p=
\rho\left(c\nabla_0+\vec{u}\cdot\vec{\nabla}\right)\vec{u}+\vec{\nabla}p$$

Using the non-relativistic approximation $\gamma\approx1$ we obtain:

$$0\approx
\rho\left(\gamma c\nabla_0+\gamma\vec{u}\cdot\vec{\nabla}\right)\gamma\vec{u}+\vec{\nabla}p=
\rho u^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}u^i+\nabla^ip$$

Compare this with the result obtained from the stress-energy tensor:

$$0=\rho u^\mu\nabla_\mu u^\nu+\nabla_\mu pc^{-2}u^\mu u^\nu+\nabla^{\nu}p$$

Why is there an extra term ($\nabla_\mu pc^{-2}u^\mu u^\nu$)? Does it vanish in the non-relativistic limit, simply because of the $c^{-2}$ factor?

Comment: To take the relativistic limit of the energy-momentum conservation equation, make the following approximation: $u^i$ small, $u^0\approx 1$, $\partial_\lambda u^\mu= \mathcal O (u^i)\; \forall \mu,\lambda;\; p=\mathcal O(u^i)$, and keep only first order terms in $u^i$. This leads to the right equation, at least for me.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\nabla_\mu (\rho u^\mu)=0$ is not correct (and not the continuity equation). Keep in mind that (based on your definition of the stress tensor) $\rho$ is the energy density, and the conserved energy current is $T_{0\mu}$.

The relativistic Euler (momentum conservation) equation is 
$$
D u_\mu = -\frac{1}{\rho+P}\nabla_\mu^\perp P
$$
where $D=u^\mu\nabla_\mu$ and $\nabla_\mu^\perp=(g_{\mu\nu}-u_\mu u_\nu)\nabla^\nu$, which shows that the relativistic inertia is the enthalpy density, $w=\rho+P$. In the non-relativistic limit, $u_0\simeq 1$, $D$ is the comoving derivative, $w$ is the mass density, and $\nabla_i^\perp\simeq\nabla_i$. This leads to the standard Euler equation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure $\nabla_\mu(\rho u^\mu) = 0$ *is* the correct continuity equation. It holds in arbitrary spacetimes for any perfect fluid with conserved rest mass density $\rho$.

Comment: No. If there is a conserved particle number, and if $\rho$ is the density of particles, and if $u_\mu$ is defined to be the velocity of the particles (the so-called Eckart frame), then this equation would be correct. But, as is clear from the expression for $T_{\mu\nu}$, $\rho$ is the energy density.

Comment: It has to be energy density, otherwise the formula for the stress tensor is wrong.

Comment: Terminology seems to be a problem here. Refer to section 3.2 ("Stress energy tensor") in http://mathreview.uwaterloo.ca/archive/voli/2/olsthoorn.pdf. It states that both $T^{\mu\nu}=(\rho+p)u^{\mu}u^{\nu}+pg^{\mu\nu}$ (assuming $\epsilon=0$) and $\nabla_\mu(\rho u^{\mu})=0$, so both equations are correct.

Comment: I think this is not just terminology. $T_{\mu\nu}=(\rho+P)u_\mu u_\nu+Pg_{\mu\nu}$ and $j_\mu=\rho u_\mu$ cannot both be correct. You can consider $\epsilon=0$ (in your notation) but i) there is no such fluid known to man (finite pressure but zero internal energy), ii) the original question is pointless, because we are in the non-relativistic limit from the start.

Comment: I do not understand why these equations cannot both be correct. i) There is no such thing as a perfect fluid either, strictly speaking. These models are approximations, and we can assume that the internal energy is negligible (relative to other parameters). ii) What do you mean by 'we are in the non-relativistic limit from the start'?

Comment: 1) The perfect fluid is a systematic approximation (gradient corrections can be made arbitrarily small by considering smooth flows, and can be accounted for order by order in the gradient expansion). 2) $\epsilon=0$ is not a systematic approximation. 3) The only thing I can imagine is that $\epsilon=0$ corresponds to neglecting internal energy compared to rest mass energy density, which is reasonable for a non-relativistic fluid. There is still no godd reason for dropping $\rho\epsilon$, but keeping $P$.